# Image storage in website: store them in database or file system?

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm developing a website with a function of picture storage. Users are able to upload their pictures and form an album.

Storing images in database or in file system, which is better? I'm using Spring MVC.

Thanks!

Comment: I wrote a few apps that store files in a DB table.  Personally, I think you are better off storing in the local filesystem. There is a lot of overhead in treating a DB as a filesystem, and the OS should already be optimized for reading/writing said file.  Much more so than any DB would.  Just my $0.02 worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of opions on this so its a very open ended question. It comes down to preference and your IT structure.

If you or your corporation have the big IT resources then you could go down the DB path as the costs (performance and finance) are mitigated by economies of scale.

If not then file system is the way to go.

Some good reading material is located here that can help you too:

http://raima.com/database-system-vs-file-system/

[http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/should-i-store-images-in-the-database-or-the-filesystem.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20150511155823/http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/should-i-store-images-in-the-database-or-the-filesystem.html)

Comment: Thanks very much. Your links help a lot